# Como faço para disparar um remote event para o server e o client no mesmo script no ROBLOX Studio?

Tags: lua, cliente-servidor

Eu ja tentei

```
remoteEvent:FireAllClients()
remoteEvent:FireServer()
```

mas não funcionou. Dizia que `FireServer` podia ser usado apenas pelo client. Eu também tentei:

```
--No server script em workspace
remoteEvent:FireClient(script.LocalScript)

--No local script em workspace.Script
remoteEvent.OnClientEvent:connect(function()
    remoteEvent:FireServer()
end)
```

mas também não funcionou. Apenas quando mudei a localização do local script para `StarterPlayer.StarterPlayerScripts` e mudando o argumento de `FireClient` para `game.StarterPlayer.StarterPlayerScripts.LocalScript` funcionou.

Ai mudei o argumento de `FireClient` para `game.Players.Player1` (o jogador de teste no Studio) e também funcionou.

Mas para complicar não posso inserir o local script no `game.StarterPlayer.StarterPlayerScripts` pois como esta pasta insere tudo que tem nela (inclusive objetos não-scripts) dentro de uma pasta chamada `PlayerScripts` dentro de um jogador que entra no jogo,todos os jogadores ficarão com o localscript que irá disparar o remote event,o qual não pode ser disparado varias vezes de uma só vez.

MAS ENFIM preciso de um script que dispare o remote event para o server e o client.

PS:Para quem quiser me ajudar,mas não tiver muita experiencia com ROBLOX Studio,vou explicar resumidamente:Server scripts irão atuar apenas no server e local scripts irão atuar no client (no PC do jogador) e remote events são objetos no qual tem 2 eventos especiais,um irá ser detectado pelos server scripts (`OnServerEvent`) e o outro  irá ser detectado pelos local scripts(`OnClientEvent`) e que pode disparar esses eventos quando "ouvir" as funções `FireServer`,`FireClient` e `FireAllClients`,as quais não preciso explicar o que irão fazer porque se vocês fazem jogos em lua é porque vocês sabem ingles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem...descobri por mim mesmo. E chamei esse método de "Master Client". Basicamente eu adicionei um remote event,um object value,um server script no `workspace` e um local script no `StarterPlayer.StarterPlayerScripts`. Escrevi isso no server script:

detalhe:`objValue` é o objeto do master client

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(player)--Bloco que irá ser executado quando um jogador entrar
    if objValue.Value==nil then--Vê se há um master client.Se não tiver...
        objValue.Value=player --Irá fazer desse jogador o master client
        print('master client agr e '..objValue.Value.Name..' :D:D:D')
    end
end)

game.Players.PlayerRemoving:connect(function(player) --Bloco que irá ser executado quando um jogador sair
    if player==objValue.Value then--Vê se esse jogador que saiu é o master client.Se é...
        print('master client saiu :(')
        objValue.Value=game.Players:GetPlayers()[1] --Irá definir um novo master client
        print('novo master client e '..objValue.Value.Name..'yaya :D:D:D')
    end
end)


rEvent.OnServerEvent:connect(function()
    print'e voala! evento disparado para o client e o server!'
end)
    while wait(1) do
        rEvent:FireAllClients()
    end

rEvent:FireAllClients()
```

E inseri isso no local script em `StarterPlayer.StarterPlayerScripts`

```
rEvent.OnClientEvent:connect(function() --Bloco que irá ser executar quando OnClientEvent for disparado
    if objValue.Value==game.Players.LocalPlayer then --Vê se o master client é o jogador local.Se é...
        print'sou euuu o tiriricaaa'
        rEvent:FireServer()
    else --Senão...
        print'nao sou eu :('
    end
end)
```

Caso não funcione,eu descobri uma outra maneira de disparar para o client e o server. Simplesmente crie um BindableEvent e dentro dele insira um RemoteEvent.

Insira isso no server script

```
bindableEvent.Event:connect(function()
    remoteEvent:FireAllClients()
end)

bindableEvent:Fire()
```

e depois insira isso no local script

```
remoteEvent.OnClientEvent:connect(function()
    print'funcionou aaaeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee'
end)
```

eu ainda não testei mas eu acho que vai funcionar.